# How do I keep single checkbox stay checked after refreshing the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

HTML code:

```
    <div class="wrap">
        <h3>Background Swap:</h3>
        <form action="" method="POST">
            <div id="checkbox-container">
                Shadowless background: <input type="checkbox" name="new_background" id="checker" <?php echo (isset($_POST['new_background']))? "checked='checked'": "";?>/><br /><br />
            </div>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upgrade Background" class="button" />
        </form>
    </div>
```

This will make the checkbox stays checked, but when page is refresh or exit and comes back, the checkbox will be unchecked. Therefore, after some research, I tried the localStorage, but doesn't seem to quite figure it out yet.

localStorage code:

```
    var checkboxValue = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('checkboxValue')) || {};
    var $checkbox = $("#checkbox-container :checkbox");

    $checkbox.on("change", function(){
        $checkbox.each(function(){
            checkboxValue[this.id] = this.checked; 
        });
        localStorage.setItem("checkboxValue", JSON.stringify(checkboxValue));
    });

    //on page load
    $.each(checkboxValue, function(key, value){
        $("#" + key).prop('checked', value);
    });
```

I have script tags around the localStorage code and after implementing these codes, my checkbox still doesn't stays checked.

Both code as a whole:

```
<div class="wrap">
<h3>Background Swap:</h3>
<form action="" method="POST">
    <div id="checkbox-container">
        Background Swap: <input type="checkbox" name="new_background"/>
    </div>
    <script>
        var checkboxValue = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('checkboxValue')) || {}
        var $checkbox = $("#checkbox-container :checkbox");

        $checkbox.on("change", function(){
            $checkbox.each(function(){
                checkboxValue[this.id] = this.checked; 
            });
            localStorage.setItem("checkboxValue", JSON.stringify(checkboxValue));
        });

        //on page load
        $.each(checkboxValue, function(key, value){
            $("#" + key).prop('checked', value);
        });
        </script>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upgrade Background" class="button"/>
</form>
</div>
```

I would like to thank everyone that took time to help me figure out the solution to my question with the biggest thanks to @Pranav C Balan!!! Check out the finished code @ http://stackoverflow.com/a/44321072/3037257

Comment: At first glance your code seems fine. Can you verify that `checkboxValue` has the value you expect; after you check a checkbox and when you reload the page?

Comment: `id="checker"` id should be unique so how many checkbox you have? just 1?

Comment: @DanielH Yes, I only have one check box.

Comment: where is the code placed in your page?

Comment: @Halcyon I'm not sure if I can, but what I'm trying to do is after checking the checkbox, it sends info to my db table and change the value of a column. It does change the value, but the checkbox unchecked after refresh page or leaving then coming back to page.

Comment: @PranavCBalan It's placed in the center of my code.

Comment: What I believe @PranavCBalan was trying to allude to was: are you sure that the checkbox exists on the page BEFORE you select it with jQuery? As in is the jQuery below the checkbox in your html?

Comment: @KongMengXiong : move your code to document ready handler or place after the form

Comment: @PatrickBarr Yes, it's under the checkbox and yes if I removed the jQuery, the checkbox would still exist.

Comment: @PranavCBalan I moved my code after the form, but nothing changed.

Comment: @KongMengXiong : please check my answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/44321072/3037257

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your code is executing before the form elements are loading, so place it at the end of your code or wrap it using [document ready handler](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) to execute only after the elements are loaded. If you were placed the code before the element `$("#checkbox-container :checkbox")` would select nothing since it is not yet loaded in the DOM.

One more thing to do, in your code the checkbox doesn't have any `id` so add a unique id to the element to make it work since the JSON is generating using the id value.

```
<div class="wrap">
  <h3>Background Swap:</h3>
  <form action="" method="POST">
    <div id="checkbox-container">
      Background Swap: <input type="checkbox" id="name" name="new_background" />
    </div>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upgrade Background" class="button" />
  </form>
  <script>
    var checkboxValue = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('checkboxValue')) || {}
    var $checkbox = $("#checkbox-container :checkbox");

    $checkbox.on("change", function() {
      $checkbox.each(function() {
        checkboxValue[this.id] = this.checked;
      });
      localStorage.setItem("checkboxValue", JSON.stringify(checkboxValue));
    });

    //on page load
    $.each(checkboxValue, function(key, value) {
      $("#" + key).prop('checked', value);
    });
  </script>
</div>
```

Working demo : [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/qxrchhoa/1/)

---

```
<script>
  // document ready handler
  // or $(document).ready(Function(){...
  jQuery(function($) {
    var checkboxValue = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('checkboxValue')) || {}
    var $checkbox = $("#checkbox-container :checkbox");

    $checkbox.on("change", function() {
      $checkbox.each(function() {
        checkboxValue[this.id] = this.checked;
      });
      localStorage.setItem("checkboxValue", JSON.stringify(checkboxValue));
    });

    //on page load
    $.each(checkboxValue, function(key, value) {
      $("#" + key).prop('checked', value);
    });
  });
</script>
<div class="wrap">
  <h3>Background Swap:</h3>
  <form action="" method="POST">
    <div id="checkbox-container">
      Background Swap: <input type="checkbox" id="name" name="new_background" />
    </div>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upgrade Background" class="button" />
  </form>

</div>
```

Working demo : [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/nh6bemyo/)

Comment: @KongMengXiong : glad to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to localStorage that only utilizes document.cookie:

```
$('input:checkbox').change(function() {
    saveCookies();
});
```

To register the function and the actual function:

```
function saveCookies() {
    var checkArray = [];
    $('input.comic-check').each(function() {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            checkArray.push(1);
        } else {
            checkArray.push(0);
        }
    });
    document.cookie = "checks=" + checkArray;
}
```

This is an alternative to localStorage, and depends on whether you want it to persist longer

And to retrieve the saved (on load)

```
var checks = getCookie("checks");
if (checks != "") {
    checkArray = checks.split(',');
    //unchecks boxes based on cookies
    //also has backwards compatability provided we only append to the list in landing.ejs/generator.js
    for (var i = 0; i < checkArray.length; i++) {
        if (checkArray[i] == "0" && $('input.comic-check').length > i) {
            var checkBox = $('input.comic-check')[i];
            $(checkBox).prop('checked', false);
        }
    }
}
function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
    var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
    for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
            c = c.substring(1);
        }
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
            return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but doesn't seems like its working or I'm not implementing it correctly

Answer (score 0):

I would change:

```
<?php echo (isset($_POST['new_background']))? "checked='checked'": "";?>
```

for:

```
<?php echo (isset($_POST['new_background']) && $_POST['new_background']=="on")? "checked" : "";?>
```

**In inline HTML**, you don't need the `checked` attribute to be `checked=checked`.
Just `checked` is enought.

`checked=checked` is used in JavaScript to programatically check a checkbox.

**EDIT**
**About your localStorage...**

I made an example for you on [**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/VWZpjJ?editors=1011)

```
//on page load, check the appropriate checkboxes.
var onloadChecks = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("checkboxValue"))
$.each(onloadChecks, function(key, value){
  $("#" + key).prop('checked', value);
});

// ================ Saving checks

// Checkboxes collection.
var allCheckboxes = $("input[type='checkbox']");

// On change handler.
allCheckboxes.on("change", function() {

  // Check how many checkboxes we have.
  var jsonCheckboxes = {};
  console.log("There is "+allCheckboxes.length+" checkboxes.");

  // Building the json.
  for(i=0;i<allCheckboxes.length;i++){
    console.log(allCheckboxes.eq(i).attr("id"));
    console.log(allCheckboxes.eq(i).is(":checked"));
    jsonCheckboxes[allCheckboxes.eq(i).attr("id")] = allCheckboxes.eq(i).is(":checked");
  }
  console.log("jsonCheckboxes: "+JSON.stringify(jsonCheckboxes));

  // Setting localStorage.
  localStorage.setItem("checkboxValue", JSON.stringify(jsonCheckboxes));
  console.log("LocalStorage: "+ localStorage.getItem("checkboxValue") );
});
```

Comment: @KongMengXiong: Your Fiddle with the jQuery library loaded works like a charm. see it updated [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Bes7weB/o3f5928u/) Note that it is "undefined" on load... Because there is no storage yet. But check the box and submit. Then reload the fiddle.

Comment: Yes, I know that I could just set the checkbox = checked, but the thing is if they(user) unchecked it won't stay unchecked. If the box = check it pass in 1 into the db table else 0 for unchecked after pressing the 'update background' button.

Comment: I edited with a working example about LocalStorage. ;)

Comment: Could I combine the two code into same file or would I need two separate files?

Comment: If you submit "to self", the PHP code in not necessary, since the data is stored locally and there is a script to use it. If you want to get rid of localStorage and the JS script, you can do it using PHP. So it's one or the other. Your choice. Both are doing the same thing. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Three situations you will need to check the checkbox

1. PHP have it set to `checked="checked"` (checked)
2. localStorage have it as `true` (checked)
3. all other situations this should be unchecked

all you need is to make sure first two situation you check the checkbox, then by default it is unchecked, but in your each you are also uncheck checkbox, therefore ignored the PHP part (as php set it to checked but localStorege set it to unchecked)

#### Example here: https://jsfiddle.net/dalinhuang/efwc7ejb/

```
//on page load
$.each(checkboxValue, function(key, value) {
    if(value){
       $("#" + key).prop('checked', value);
    }
});
```

Comment: If I want a single checkbox, how would I change the localStorage code?

Comment: @KongMengXiong single checkbox and you know the id you can just do this https://jsfiddle.net/dalinhuang/dehcunxL/

Comment: Yes, I know that I could just set the checkbox = checked, but the thing is if they unchecked it won't stay unchecked. If the box = check it pass in 1 into the db table else 0 for unchecked after pressing the 'update background' button.

Comment: @KongMengXiong so you want just follow localStorage? ignore php if localStorage have a true/false been set?

Comment: Well, my goal is to find something that will make my checkbox stays checked if the user choose to, so it doesn't have to be localStorage if you think other things would be more efficient like cookie.

Answer (score 0):

Working around your comment : `my goal is to find something that will make my checkbox stays checked if the user choose to`, here's a way to have the localStorage handle it :

> jQuery (3.2.1)

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var bground = localStorage.getItem('background'); // get the value if exists

if (bground == 'shadow') { // checkbox has been previously checked
    $('#checker').attr('checked', 'checked');
}
if (bground == 'shadowless') { // checkbox has been previously unchecked
    $('#checker').attr('');
}

$('#submit').submit(function() { // when form is submitted
    bground = localStorage.getItem('background'); // get the value in LS
    if($('#checker').is(':checked')) // is it checked or not ?
    { sh = 'shadow'; } else { sh = 'shadowless'; }
    localStorage.setItem('background', sh); // update LS with new value
}); 

});
```

> HTML (added `id="submit"` to form)

```
<form action="" id="submit" method="POST">
  <div id="checkbox-container">
  Shadowless background: <input type="checkbox" name="new_background" id="checker" /><br />
  </div>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upgrade Background" class="button" />
</form>
```

This will make the checkbox stays checked, and when page is refreshed, the checkbox will be checked/unchecked depending on user's previous choice.

*You could also use the jQuery `change` function instead of form submitting.
Just modify the line :*

```
$('#submit').submit(function() { // comment/delete this line
// to the one below
// $('#checker').change(function() { // uncomment this line
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't seem to work for me. Maybe i'm inputing it incorrectly. Thanks though!!